# Auto-Create User Login from Wordpress to Perfex CRM

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, cookies, credentials

I go straight to the Problem:

1. User creates an account on my WordPress Website
2. User decides to use the Support-Center (Perflex CRM)
3. User gets redirected to the Support Website
4. -> Problem: User will have to create an EXTRA account for the Support System

---

Question:

Is there any way to create automaticly an account for him with his Wordpress Credentials (Username, Email and Password)?

And/Or Additionally skip entering credentials (maybe with cookies?) and let him Log in straight into the just created account?

How would I archieve this in a safe/secure matter, is it even possible with the Perfex .php script?

---

Additional Infos:

Login Options on my WP Site: Standart method (Email/Pass), Google or Facebook.

---

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy, just install or write a module for Perfex to allow add a custom script to the frontend,or find in web "Custom JavaScript module for Perfex",

Ad Redirection link from WordPress site with  email and password for example :

```
// https://your.project.com/authentication/login?email=test@test.com&password=securePass
```

**Warning:** Remember about security issue if you send a plain password:

Apply this code to module :

```
<script>
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
const email = urlParams.get('email');
const password = urlParams.get('password');
document.querySelector('#email').value = email;
document.querySelector('#password').value = password;
// call function once
let clickButton = (function() {
    let executed = false;
    return function() {
        if (!executed) {
            executed = true;
           document.querySelector(".btn").click();
        }
    };
})();
clickButton()
</script>
```

Comment: Sending in plain password looks highly insecure. How did you do OP?